# Merge local master branch into remote sub branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have cloned a repository from master branch and did lots of modifications. Suddenly I remembered that I'm using the master brach and I wanted to commit it to newly created remote branch not the master branch.Actually I'm very new to git. please help me,Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you made changes to wrong branch then do `git checkout -b newBranchName`.
This will move all changes to new branch named `newBranchName`

Then do `git branch` to see which branch are you currently working on.

If this is the `newBranchName` then do

```
git add . //stages all changed files
git commit -m "any message here" //commit with a message
git push -u origin newBranchName //push local branch to remote with name newBranchName
```

Doing this will push your local branch to a new remote branch named `newBranchName`

Now doing `git checkout master` will again take you back to you local master branch.

Cross check which branch are you currently at by `git branch`

If this shows master with green color or `*master` then do 
`git reset --hard HEAD` to revert back the changes you have made in your local.

Once you reset it then your local master branch will be exactly same as remote master branch.

Comment: Thank for your time. I will checkout that.

Comment: Someone down voted my answer. If you find this helpful please do upvote it and it solved your problem then do accept the solution.

Comment: Actually not. Any way I solved it with hard way. I created new branch and Hard-Coded all the changes I did. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common workflow mistake.  One simple option is to create a new branch from your current point in `master`, then revert your local `master` branch back to the point right before you started working:

```
# from master
# git commit any outstanding changes
git branch feature
git reset --hard HEAD~2   # replace 2 with the actual number of commits you did make
```

This assumes that you made *two* commits to your local `master` branch before you realized you were on the wrong branch.  The hard reset command simply removes those commits, which however are now still part of the `feature` branch.  You may now push `feature` to the remote if you want to do that.

Comment: Faster: `git checkout -b feature; git branch -f master origin/master`. No worktree churn.

Comment: @jthill Nice trick, but that might assume the OP has not done a fetch in between, or, if it has, that it is OK reverting `master` back to some other starting point.